# How to show array in other view SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to show array values, which I get from API call. I'm making `addToCart` request in one view and need to show its result in other view.

```
class Cart: ObservableObject {

@Published var data: ShoppingCartContent?
@Published var sections: [SectionContent] = []
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>() }

extension Cart {

func addToCart(productId: Int, productQty: Int) {
    
    guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") else { return }
    NetworkManager.addProductToCart(token: token, productId: productId, productQty: productQty)
        .sink(
          receiveCompletion: { completion in
              switch completion {
              case .finished:
                  print("finished")
              case .failure(let error):
                  print("AddToCart error", error)
              }
          },
          receiveValue: { value in
              print("Success:", value.success)
              print("Data:", value.data)
              self.data = value.data
              self.sections = value.data.sections
              print("Sections:", self.sections)
          })
        .store(in: &subscriptions) }}
```

I'm getting data from API, save them in @Published var sections, but I can't show them in other view, print shows it's nil.

```
struct ShoppingView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: Cart

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
    HStack {
        Text("Delivery:")
            .foregroundColor(Color.textFieldGrayColor)
          
        ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
            ForEach(section.items, id: \.self) { product in
                Text(product.product_name)
            }
        }
}

}.onAppear {
 print("My cart arr:", cartViewModel.data?.sections)
}
}
}
```

P.S. `ShoppingView` - is one of the tabs, I added (environmentObject) in `MainView`

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: Cart
ShoppingView().environmentObject(viewModel)
```

I also tried to access array with `@ObservedObject var viewModel = Cart()` but it also shows empty array.

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend using `ShoppingView().environmentObject(Cart())`: this will create a new `Cart` instance every time the view is called. You will finish by re-creating the contents of your variables each time.

What I propose is to replace this call in your original code *in the MainView*:

`@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: Cart`

with:

`@StateObject var viewModel = Cart()`

This will create a StateObject in the MainView that will be passed to `ShoppingView` through the environment. Depending on your needs, also `let viewModel = Cart()` works.

Comment: You mean in ShoppinView I should declare @StateObject var viewModel = Cart() and what about MainView and ProductDetail? How I should declare viewModel in these views?

Comment: I mean, in **MainView** you should declare your _one and only_ instance of `Cart`. Then, pass this instance (that in MainView you called `viewModel`) to all other views using `.environmentObject(viewModel)`. If you pass it to one of the views, all child views will automatically receive the same environment object, so the array in the Cart object will always be the same for all views. In ProductDetail and ShoppingView you maintain `@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: Cart`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally understand it.

Comment: @HunterLion Where is the source that a `Cart` instance is created *every time the view is called?* I disagree. `.environmentObject(Cart())` works exactly like `@StateObject` where only the initial view owns the view model, and `@EnvironmentObject` works  like `@ObservedObject`. The benefit of `@EnvironmentObject` is that you don't need to hand over the object through the entire view hierarchy.

Comment: @vadian: you are correct, as long as you pass `.environmentObject(Cart())` only once in your code since the beginning. If instead you use it in a view, changing the state of that view might create a new instance in the environment - not in every case, but it depends on how your code works. I just proposed an approach which I deem safer to use everywhere. But your solution can work.

Answer (score 1):

When you are going to inject the view model you have to create an instance

Replace

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: Cart
ShoppingView().environmentObject(viewModel)
```

with

```
ShoppingView().environmentObject(Cart())
```

The `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper is only necessary if you inherit the object.

Comment: Replaced. Nothing changed :( You think array is empty due to this.

Comment: Where do you call `addToCart`?

Comment: In ProductDetailView, @ObservedObject var cartViewModel = Cart() cartViewModel.addToCart(productId: product.id, productQty: self.productCount)

Comment: There `Cart()` is a different instance. Use the instance in the  environment. And you have to use `@StateObject` if you **own** the object.

Comment: I should declare @EnvironmentObject var cartViewModel: Cart in ProductDetail?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but `ProductDetail` must be a descendant of `MainView`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works! So the problem was that when I use EnvironmentObject I should use it also in ProductDetail. I didn't think that they're linked to each other.

Comment: Please read [this explanation of EnvironmentObject](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/environmentobject/)