# SwiftUI Architecture - Using ObservableObjects to control Views

Tags: swiftui, architecture

From an architecture point of view, is it a good idea to use Published properties to control UI elements in a SwiftUI view hierarchy?

Consider the following problem,

I have a store as such

```
@MainActor final class SomeStore: ObservableObject {
   @Published var shouldShowSuccessAlert: Boolean = false
   @Published var someData: String = false

   //Called by some networking library 
   public func networkRequestDidComplete(with data: String) {
      self.someData = data
      self.shouldShowSuccessAlert = false
   }
}

//App
struct SomeApp: App {
    @StateObject private var someStore: SomeStore = SomeStore()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SomeView(shouldShowSuccessAlert: self.someStore.shouldShowSuccessAlert)
        }
    }

}

//View
struct SomeView: View { 
   @ObservedObject private var someStore: SomeStore
   
   var body: some View {
      if self.someStore.shouldShowSuccessAlert {
         //some arbitrary alertView
         AlertView(onComplete: {
            self.someStore.shouldShowSuccessAlert = false
         })
      }
   }
}
```

The only problem I can see is that changing this one Boolean will cause the entire view hierarchy to re-render. If SomeView has a deep view hierarchy, all of its descendants will be re-rendered. In React, for example, there is a concept of a PureComponent that you can use to prevent re-renders of views (called components in React) only if the properties they use change (by using reference equality checks) in order to improve performance. Is there something similar in SwiftUI?

Are there any other patterns that can be used like absorbing this boolean into the view's state and then controlled locally within the view?

Comment: You aren’t objecting the variable in SomeView use Binding Demystify SwiftUI  from WWDC 21 might clear up some stuff.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use StateObject directly in SomeView? Even if I did, won't it still re-render all the descendants of SomeView?

Comment: You can inject your `@StateObject` from the `App` in the environment  using `.environmentObject(someStore)` and read it in any view you want (*if* you want!) using `@EnvironmentObject`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234044/how-to-show-array-in-other-view-swiftui/71235833#71235833).

Comment: You are recreating the view because you aren’t observing the change and you are changing the identify of the View with the change https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Comment: You also seem to be initializing the StateObject in some odd way  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Create a symbolic init and put a print statement in it you will see how many times you are recreating the view instead of just the changes.

Comment: @HunterLion, I prefer explicitly passing data using initializers instead of EnvironmentObject because I prefer to see how data flows throughout my views. Makes it easier to debug errors. For theming and other such cases, I use EnvironmentObject.

Comment: @loremipsum I didn't put all the details of the implementation in the sample. But I am following exactly what is written in the article you've shared. I've updated the example for you to see.

Comment: honestly though @loremipsum it only recreates the view as many times as shouldShowSuccessAlert changes which is the expected outcome. But the issue is that won't this re-render all descendants of SomeView? And what other approaches are there?

Comment: Everything that is affected by the if and hopefully there is an an else because you change the identity was the WWDC video they address this exact thing. And don’t use self, there is another video about that but I can’t remember which one it is. Just use the variable without the self. It is a struct there fire immutable if you hang on to the self when SwiftUI does the mutating the self changes therefore the identify changes. Let the wrappers hand on to the identity as designed.

Comment: You can try and reduce the rerendering but ultimately SwiftUI recreates Views whenever it wants Apple has always been clear about that, it’s even mentioned in that link. The only thing you can do is make sure you provide consistent data for each render. I don’t know what lead to the question but I’m assuming something is resetting down the line SceneStorage might be a solution for you.

Comment: I was asking not because of an performance issue so far, but because coming from a React background (which is what made Declarative UI popular and which SwiftUI is based on in principle), has constructs in place to ensure that the view hierarchy remains performative but can't seem SwiftUI seems to have these constructs. Could be coming in later versions perhaps.

Comment: Maybe, June is coming soon there should be a lot of announcement along with the Intel phase out plan.